# Turning binary data into string data in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have some raw data on Excel that is organized in a way that is not easily readable. For example, for a table showing which user likes which color:

```
        A      B        C       D       E
User | Red | Green | Orange | Blue | Yellow
A       0      1        0       1       0
B       0      0        1       1       0
C       1      0        0       0       1
```

So, user A likes Green and Blue, B likes Orange and Blue, and C likes Red and Yellow.

This is useful for us because I can use this to calculate frequency, but I also need the data in human readable form.

I would like to add a single column that says the colors that a user picked, like: User A - Green + Blue.

But I can't seem to do this with `CONCATENATE(IF(A2=1, $A$1), +, IF(B2=1, $B$1))` and so on because the `IF` function doesn't work inside `CONCATENATE`. I also cannot add too many columns because my data has multiple columns already.

Is there a function I can use to turn this binary data into a clean string that can fit in on column?

Comment: You may want to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without the `CONCATENATE()` function...

[image: Results]

```
=TRIM(IF(B2=1;B$1;"")&IF(C2=1;" "&C$1;"")&IF(D2=1;" "&D$1;"")&IF(E2=1;" "&E$1;"")&IF(F2=1;" "&F$1;""))
```

The `TRIM()` function removes any excess spaces which may appear if the user likes Green but not Red.

Comment: I think you want to change your semicolons to commas.

Comment: @Fezter no. Semicolon vs commas is a region restriction. For the formula to work here in Norway I need to use semicolons, for the formula to work where you are maybe you need commas.

Comment: Yeah I had to change to commas for it to work. I had no idea there were regional settings like that.

Comment: Its annoying and took me a long time to come to terms with when I moved from the UK to Norway. But now im used to is :)

Answer (score 3):

If you have Office 365 / Excel 2016, you can use the `TEXTJOIN` function in an array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,IF(B2:F2=1,$B$1:$F$1,""))
```

Since this is an array formula, you need to "confirm" it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar.

[image]